# How to change color in multiple element or art-board?

Tags: photoshop, adobe-xd

How to change multiple element color in one click or How change multiple art-board element color in one click like without selection every element in **Photoshop** and **Adobe XD** both?

Comment: Please read this first — https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask — and edit your question with more information. What's an _element_, to what color, with click or on artboard (the answers will be different), in PS or XD (the answers will be different) and what you've tried already.

Comment: Once you've added info to your question, you may want to consider posting it on https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/ instead of here (Stackoverflow is more concerned with programming problems than general software usage)